# Reset WebGL viewport with canvas resize

Tags: webgl, viewport

In my WebGL program I am changing my canvas height and width based on some event and I am trying to update my viewport with gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height) command every time the event occurs.

But my viewport is not updating (or as it seems like) and my drawn object goes out of scene. I tried adding some offset to enlarge/decrease my viweport but evenif the viewport increases it put a black screen at the side and the objects goes behind the screen.

Can any body suggest what should I do to change my viewport according to canvas height and width change and show all the objects? I am not using any library. I checked some other posts here regarding this issue, but still not able to find a solution.

Thanks,
Adnan

Comment: Are you updating your projection matrix as well?

Comment: Hi, I have not used projection matrix. Is it necessary? However whenever there is a change is objects position, I update the viewport too by calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your WebGL canvas size by changing the **style** size in `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height`, wait for CSS to layout your canvas again, and then change the canvas **content** size in `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`.  Finally, you should reset your GL projection matrix and viewport to use `gl.drawingBufferWidth` and `gl.drawingBufferHeight`.  That way, your app handles whatever CSS does when laying out your resized canvas, and whatever GL does when allocating a drawing buffer to fit the canvas content.  For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Resize WebGL</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="resizeButton" value="resize"><br>
<canvas id="chart" style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000;">
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
        var gl = null;

        function resetGL() {
            var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
            var w = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio);
            var h = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio);
            if (canvas.width != w || canvas.height != h) {
                console.log("resetGL: Setting canvas.width=" + w + " canvas.height=" + h);

                canvas.width = w;
                canvas.height = h;
            }
            if (!gl || gl.isContextLost()) {
                gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
                console.log("Allocated WebGL context: " + gl);
            }
        }

        function redraw() {
            requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                resetGL();
                gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
                gl.clearColor(1, 0.8, 1, 1);
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                // Draw your stuff here
            });
        }

        var bToggle = false;
        function resize() {
            bToggle = !bToggle;
            var s = bToggle ? '50px' : '100px';
            console.log("");
            console.log("Button: Setting canvas.style.width=" + s + " canvas.style.height=" + s);
            canvas.style.width = s;
            canvas.style.height = s;
            redraw();
        }
        var button = document.getElementById('resizeButton');
        button.addEventListener("click", resize);
        redraw();
    </script>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: In iOS you may need to force devicePixelRatio to 1 to avoid an apparent bug in iOS Safari.  Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745878/resize-webgl-context-in-ios) for details.